# How to cache HashMap data for "n" number of iteration

Tags: java, caching, hashmap

I got this question from one of my friends.

Problem) I want to write a class which can cache data for "n" iterations for each key and after which it will fetch data from database.
After fetching the data from database again for that key it should fetch data only after "n" iteration. For each fetch might be from database or cache the iteration count should be reduced.

Question 1) Which is the best approach extending HashMap or writing a class which holds a HashMap
Question 2) Write the code for the above problem.

I have written the below code. Please suggest me with any better approach for doing this.

```
    public class CacheHashMap {

    private int iterationValue = 3;
    static Map<String, String> dbSimulator = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<String, String> cacheMap;
    private Map<String, Integer> iterationMap;

    static{
        dbSimulator.put("Vijay","VJ");
        dbSimulator.put("Smith","SM");
        dbSimulator.put("Raj","RJ");
    }

    public CacheHashMap(Map valueMap, int n) {
        this.iterationValue = n;
        if(null != valueMap){
            this.cacheMap = valueMap;
            this.iterationMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:cacheMap.entrySet()){
                iterationMap.put(entry.getKey(), iterationValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getValue(String key){
        if(null != cacheMap && null != iterationMap){
            if(cacheMap.containsKey(key)){
                if(0 == iterationMap.get(key)){
                    cacheMap.put(key, dbSimulator.get(key));
                    iterationMap.put(key, (iterationValue-1));
                    return cacheMap.get(key);
                }else{
                    iterationMap.put(key, (iterationMap.get(key)-1));
                    return cacheMap.get(key);
                }
            }else{
                cacheMap.put(key, dbSimulator.get(key));
                iterationMap.put(key, (iterationValue-1));
                return cacheMap.get(key);
            }
        }
        return "No data found. Please enter a valid key";
    }

    public void printCacheMap(){
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:cacheMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Cache Map Data\tKey:: " + entry.getKey() + "\tValue:: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void printIterationMap(){
        System.out.println("==================================================================");
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry:iterationMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Iteration Map Data\tKey:: " + entry.getKey() + "\tValue:: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}



public class CacheHashMapExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        CacheHashMap cacheHashMap = new CacheHashMap(myMap, 3);
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Vijay");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Raj");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Smith");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Vijay");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Raj");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Vijay");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Raj");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Vijay");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
        cacheHashMap.getValue("Raj");cacheHashMap.printCacheMap();cacheHashMap.printIterationMap();
    }

}
```

Comment: It's good that you did not choose to extend `HashMap` but compose it - that is the correct choice. Maintaining parallel collections is, however, the mistake of many a rookie programmer and shows "object phobia". Wrap the behaviour of an individual cache value into a `CacheValue` class.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for Code Review and is therefore more suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks for the suggestion. I am quite new to stackoverflow, next time i will keep this kind of questions under code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st question: I would also compose with HashMap, instead of extending it, because your Cache system ISN'T a HashMap ; it just HAS a HashMap.

2nd: I would do this way:

```
public class CacheHashMap {

    private int iterationValue = 3;
    static Map<String, String> dbSimulator = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private Map<String, CacheItem> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();

    static{
        dbSimulator.put("Vijay","VJ");
        dbSimulator.put("Smith","SM");
        dbSimulator.put("Raj","RJ");
    }

    public CacheHashMap(int n) {
        this.iterationValue = n;
    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
        CacheItem item = cacheMap.get(key);
        if (item == null || item.isExpired()) {
            // Load from DB
            String value = dbSimulator.get(key);
            cacheMap.put(key, new CacheItem(iterationValue, value));
            return value;
        } else {
            return item.getValue();
        }
    }

    private class CacheItem {
        private int iteration;
        private String value;

        public CacheItem(int iteration, String value) {
            this.iteration = iteration;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public boolean isExpired() {
            iteration--;
            return iteration < 0;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a inner class "CacheItem" that prevent you from having to maintain 2 different maps, with the risk of having inconsistent keys. And in addition, there's some improvements, I think, in the algorithm of reading/writing the cache.